# QFileDialog disable buttons

Tags: qt, qt4, qfiledialog

I'd like to create a subclass of QFileDialog which will be used to open only directories with some particular content. I can set my own proxy model to handle behavior of files list but how can I disable/enable ok button?
Do I have to create my own widget?

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to do that by install a [proxy model](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qfiledialog.html#setProxyModel) to filter files and directories according to your criteria.

EDIT:

This only works with files by hiding unwanted files. But you can't hide directories since you need to allow navigation into them.

For picking directories, you will have to built your own dialog. An yes, I think it's a deficiency in Qt.

Comment: Yes but I cannot enable/disable QPushButton using Proxy Model.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to do the following to get the "Save" button:

```
QDialogButtonBox *button_box = findChild<QDialogButtonBox *>();
QPushButton *save_button;

if (button_box) {
    save_button = button_box->button(QDialogButtonBox::Save); // depends on acceptMode()
}
```